# How to get value from DropdownList in postback from ViewModel Type of Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have used a ViewModel, which has 2 different models.
1) Model of Details of a Person
2)List of Hobbies

```
 public class DetailsandHobbyVM
{
    public List<HobbyMastr> hobbiesVM { get; set; }

    public DetailsMaster detailsVM { get; set; }
}
```

Here are these models.

1) HobbyMastr

```
 public partial class HobbyMastr
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public HobbyMastr()
    {
        this.DetailsMasters = new HashSet<DetailsMaster>();
    }

    public int HobbyId { get; set; }
    public string HobbyName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<DetailsMaster> DetailsMasters { get; set; }
}
```

2)DetailsMaster

```
  public partial class DetailsMaster
{
    public int DetailsId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> HobbyId { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Gender { get; set; }

    public virtual HobbyMastr HobbyMastr { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller ActionMethod where I am trying to get the values in argument Object of type DetailsandHobbyVM

```
  public ActionResult DetailsPost(DetailsandHobbyVM p)
    { }
```

Here is the View

```
@model DemoWebsite.ViewModel.DetailsandHobbyVM

@using (Html.BeginForm("DetailsPost", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.detailsVM.Name)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.detailsVM.Image)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.hobbiesVM, new SelectList(Model.hobbiesVM, "HobbyId", "HobbyName"))

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.detailsVM.Gender, 1) @*//Male*@

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.detailsVM.Gender, 2) @*//Female*@

<input type="submit" value="SubmitMe!" />}
```

Now I am trying to send all these values to DetailsPost ActionMethod but all the fields in (p object) are receiving values except HobbyId.

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the field for the selected value in DropDownListFor method. If you change from m.detailsVM to m.detailsVM.HobbyId, the value in DetailsMaster's HobbyId will be populated.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.detailsVM.HobbyId, new SelectList(Model.hobbiesVM, "HobbyId", "HobbyName"))
```